# Duplicate birthday calendar entries

Tags: calendar

After my upgrade to Catalina 10.15 I started getting duplicate birthdays and duplicate contacts on my Mac. I was able to take care of the duplicate contacts by deleting the unneeded contact after trial and error. I ended up using the note section to put a random letter in my phone contacts and seeing which one updated on my Mac and seeing which one updated. Then I deleted the one that didn't update.

Regarding duplicate birthdays I read previous posts and on my Mac unchecked, in Contacts, "Birthdays" and rechecked it again, waited, then unchecked and rechecked it. I went back into Calendar on my Mac and the duplicate birthdates were gone. I've checked it several times since and so far so good.

Does anyone else have a suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem recently after installing MacOS 12.1, Monterey. It was fixed by following:

- Open Contacts,
- Click the Card menu (top of screen), choose Look for duplicates, choose Merge.

  Each pair of duplicate cards will be merged into a single card that contains all the information from both cards. (I'm not sure what would happen if there were two cards for one person but one contained old (outdated) info and the other contained recent (current) info.)
- Finally, go to Calendar, where only one set of birthdays should be seen.